# Slow download speed on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, performance

When I built my computer I only had a Windows 7 disk lying around, so I installed Windows 7; Internet worked completely fine and didn't have any issues with the download speed.
I then downloaded Windows 10 onto a USB stick and ran a fresh install (since I read that upgrade installs can cause problems); the first time round the download speed was fine, but now my download speed is incredibly slow.

This doesn't seem to be related to a [current ongoing problem with the motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1072866/why-wont-my-motherboard-work-with-two-cpus) as Internet worked fine in Windows 7.

On testing the speed, I found that I get a maximum of 3Mbps download and 0.96Mbps upload:

[image]

The Internet connection is rated at a maximum of 20Mbps download and 1Mbps upload; it seems that while the download speed has been impacted, upload speed is not. When I download anything, the entire Internet connectivity of the machine is bottlenecked by the program doing the download; this doesn't usually happen as my router's QoS prevents this from happening.

Thinking that it was a driver issue, I reinstalled the driver for the Ethernet (Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection) with no effect. I then [downloaded and installed the driver for my motherboard from the manufacturer's website](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTi-F.cfm), again to no effect.

I read that [disabling “Large Send Offload (LSO)](http://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/2806-slow-network-throughput-windows-10-a.html) could fix the problem; I have done so but yet again, to no effect. I've also done the standard stuff of rebooting the router & verifying the speed with another Ethernet device.

I also ran a speed-test on my phone, and it's the normal speed (so the router or the actual Internet connection isn't the issue here):

[image]

There are also quite a few settings in the Ethernet adapter's properties; perhaps one of these could be the cause?

The settings are as follows:

> - Interrupt Moderation : Disabled;
> - Jumbo Packet : Disabled;
> - Large Send Offload (IPv4 & IPv6) : Disabled;
> - Locally Administered Address : None;
> - Log Link State Event : Enabled;
> - Performance Options :
>
>   - Flow Control : Rx & Tx Enabled;
>   - Interrupt Moderation Rate : Adaptive;
>   - Low Latency Interrupts : Disabled;
>   - Receive Buffers : 256;
>   - Transmit Buffers : 512
> - Priority & VLAN : Priority Enabled;
> - Receive Side Scaling : Disabled;
> - Receive Side Scaling Queues : 1 Queue;
> - TCP/IP Offloading Options : None Checked;
> - Wait for Link : Off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this issue isn't driver-related at all; rather, it is related to a combination of the powerline adapter I'm using and the actual plug socket.

Someone told me that a high load can disrupt communications for PoE adapters, and that seems to have rung true in my case; the issue can be tracked back to when I first started gaming with the machine. **However, the 362W maximum output should *not* be high enough to disrupt PoE communications; therefore it can be determined that the PoE adapter is faulty.**

The combination of the 'high' load and faulty PoE adapter led to a disruption in the PoE adapter's communications.

Since the PoE adapter is faulty, my solution is to RMA it for warranty replacement. TP Link's [warranty page](http://uk.tp-link.com/support/rma/) states that:

> If you are experiencing product defects within the warranty period, please FIRST contact the online/retail store where you originally purchased the product(s) to ensure a rapid replacement.

Therefore I'm contacting the original retailer for an exchange/replacement, which is Amazon.